# Isomorphisms between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not quite following the section of the solution highlighted. Why if (yx)^2 is equal to an element of order p, does that in turn mean yx has order p?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't - the proof shows that $(yx)^2$ has order $p$, so $(yx)^{2p}=1$. This means that the order of $yx$ divides $2p$, and thus must be $2$, $p$ or $2p$ because $p$ is prime. It doesn't have order $2$, because $(yx)^2=x^{i+1}\ne1$, and it doesn't have order $p$ by the argument given. Hence the order of $yx$ is $2p$.